# Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CBaseVideoRenderer

Tags: c++, directx, directshow

I am updating some old code. Everything compiled fine. But I am stuck on (I think) simple thing.

```
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CBaseVideoRenderer"
```

I have built the latest DirectShow lib both in Unicode and MBCS. And it still gives me this compile error. It gives me no error in the code. What is here wrong?

EDIT:
Here is the file where CBaseVideoRendere. 
https://github.com/pixelspark/tjshow/blob/master/ShowControl/TJShow/src/view/tjtexturerenderer.h
(I have updated the DirectShow. But it is not ready to go in the git. So there is a different version)

Comment: Are you linking with `Strmbase.lib`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368855(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have linked the strmbase.lib. Everything else works fine from that lib.

Comment: Maybe you also need to import evr.lib

Comment: Stil does not work :( Is there an alternative for DirectShow. I'm kinda sick of this kind of problems :p

Comment: Eventually, this kind of problem comes up when you have (a) lost symbol you need to include, and you easily identify it by error message, or (b) mismatching compiler settings in projects you are trying to link into binary.

Comment: I checked everything. And it should be fine